# Limit Comment in Post Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

So this is the problem, I have application with post and comment. But I want to limit the comment per user, So if there is 1 post only 1 comment per user. Is it possible ?

Here is my `store` function in `CommentController`:

```
public function store(Request $request, $post)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'title' => 'required|max:200',
        'desc' => 'required|max:800'
    ));
    $comments = new Comment();
    $comments->id_user = Auth::id();
    $comments->id_post = $post;
    $comments->title = $request->A;
    $comments->desc = $request->B;
    $comments->save();
    return redirect()->route('controller.index');
}
```

What query can I add in this `store` function to limit the user to only comment once in 1 post. Thanks guys hope you can help me.

Comment: What is `$incase`? What is the ID of the post that this comment is for?

Comment: im sorry already edit it

Comment: Depending on your logic, I am assuming you have a table with the comments. That should include a post id and a comment id as well as a user id. The post id links the comment to the post, the comment id is the primary key of the comment table, and user id is linked to the user who made the comment. You then do a count on comment id in the comment table where post id is equal to the post in question and where the user id matches the id of the user. Then make an if statement around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple you need to check if a comment for a user and post already exists like this:

```
if (! Comment::where('id_user', $userId)->where('id_post', $postId)->exists()) {
   //save the comment
} else {
   // do not save the comment
}
```

In your case `$userId` may be `Auth::user()->id`, and the $postId is `$post->id`.

Comment: what is $userid and $postid, it is undefined variable ?

Comment: I've updated the answer, but you already should figure out alone what is $userId and $postId...

Answer (score 2):

You should try this

*Check comment added for this post by this user*

```
$result = DB::table('comments')->where('id_user', '=', Auth::id())->where('id_post', '=', $incase->id)->get();

if(count($result) < 1){
    $comments = new Comment();
    $comments->id_user = Auth::id();
    $incase = Incase::find($id);
    $comments->id_post = $incase->id;
    $comments->title = $request->A;
    $comments->desc = $request->B;
    $comments->save();
    return redirect()->route('controller.index');
}
else{
    return redirect()->route('controller.index')->with('warning','Already Commented');
}
```

**OR**

*Hide Comment box for that user if one comment stored*